# Bootstrap UI Datepicker Limit days per month

Tags: angularjs

html code::

```
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter date"
        uib-datepicker-popup="{{$ctrl.datePicker.format}}" ng-model="$ctrl.date" is-open="$ctrl.isOpened"
        datepicker-options="$ctrl.datePicker.dateOptions" ng-required="true" name="name" popup-placement="auto bottom-right"
        ng-click="$ctrl.openDatePicker($ctrl.date)" data-ng-model-options="{ 'debounce': 300}"/>
```

controller code::

```
$ctrl.datePicker = {
        format : 'MM-dd-yy',
        dateOptions: {
          dateDisabled: false,
          formatYear: 'yy',
          maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
          minDate: today,
          startingDay: 1,
          showButtonBar: false,
          altInputFormats: ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'],
          showWeeks: false,
          ngModelOptions: {
            debounce: 100
          }
        },
        isOpened: false
      };
```

I want to hide last row in uib-datepicker which is not useful. It's shows next month day. Please see image

[image]

Comment: @RameshRajendran it angularjs, not jQuery

Comment: I used bootstrap uib-datepicker. I checked other issue but I am still not getting my answer. Can you please help me if possible?